# AJAX call to Handler fails for POST but works for GET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, handler

Here's my problem:

I am making an Ajax to call to a Handler. This works if I do a GET, but if I do a POST, I get Network Error 404 Not found. How is this possible ?

```
  var jsondata = { zip: myzip, country: mycountry }; // this contains data

  $.ajax({
    url: "/upstracker/timeintransit/",
    data: jsondata,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",  // This fails - giving 404 error.
    // type: "GET", // This works
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(jqXHR);
    } 
});
```

**Handler**:

```
  Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

     // All logic to create data - ServicesEstimatedDatelist Contains List of required data

      Dim jSearializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
    context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
    context.Response.Write(jSearializer.Serialize(ServicesEstimatedDatelist))
End Sub
```

The rewrite link for the Handler, is set in the rewrite rule file, which is working.

Comment: may be your endpoint does not except post?

Comment: It should, I don't see a reason why not.

Comment: change dataType to json. jsonp and post cannot be used together. This is because jsonp creates a script tag and the script can only be GET.

Comment: I think, in url you may have to provide handler name like this - url: "/upstracker/timeintransit/YourHandler.ashx". and it still if its not work then try using **$.Post()**

Comment: @HankLapidez I tried that too, actually with jsonp I was giving a callback. Thats the reason why I did jsonp. Let me correct it in the question.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana I have written a rewrite rule in webconfig to use that URL. It's working for GET.

Comment: @Ani Whats method signature of your handler look like?

Comment: @Ani Works is when you omit the data?

Comment: No, it works with GET...You still need the data

Comment: I found the problem. I am so sorry. I made a stupid mistake

Comment: @Ani: have you tried to pass data using JSON.Stringify(data)...

Comment: @KrishnrajRana I found the probel. Thanks alot for helping.

Comment: Thanks to @HankLapidez too. Your first comment got me thinking and led to the answer.

Comment: Your welcome.  Arrow up would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason I was unable to do the **POST** was because:

While adding the rewrite rule in webconfig for the Handler, I had restricted it to **GET**:

Example:

```
<add name="UPSTime_in_Transit_tracker" verb="GET" path="/upstracker/timeintransit" type="NameOfHandler"/>
```

**Versus**

```
<add name="UPSTime_in_Transit_tracker" verb="*" path="/upstracker/timeintransit" type="NameOfHandler"/>
```

Comment: Oh yes...it should be "*" instead of only "get".